# ¿Cómo mostrar tooltip mientras condiciono el elemento?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

estoy tratando de añadir un tooltip de Bootstrap con algunas propiedades peri éste no se muestra cuando lo pongo de la siguiente manera.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("._diifem_").prop("disabled", true);
$('#wall').on('keyup', function () {
    var textarea_value = $("#wall").val();
    if (textarea_value.length > 5) {
        $('._diifem_').prop({
            disabled: false,
        });
    } else {
        $('._diifem_').prop({
            disabled: true
        }).tooltip({
            title: 'Hola',
            trigger: "click"
        });
    }
   });
});
```

Lo que hace es que, cuando un campo de texto (textarea) está vació, deshabilita un botón, para ello quiero añadirle un tooltip que muestre la advertencia.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: trigger: click es para que el tooltip se muestre cuando le haces click al elemento. usa el default (borra el trigger) y fijate si funciona. Si podes todo en un fiddle va a ser mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por responder. https://jsfiddle.net/a9vdawa3/1/ Aquí el fiddle para que eches un vistazo. Por cierto, ya intenté con todos los trigger pero ninguno me funciona :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente tooltip no es muy propenso a ser manejado dinamicamente, una vez que el title obtiene en el tooltip, se crea una propiedad que es "original-title", cambiando esa propiedad se soluciona lo que necesitas:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('._diifem_').prop({
      disabled: true
    }).tooltip({
      title : "Debes ingresar por lo menos un caracter"
    });
    $('#wall').on('keyup', function () {
        var textarea_value = $("#wall").val();
        if (textarea_value.length >= 1) {
            $('._diifem_').prop({
                disabled: false,
            }).attr('data-original-title','Enviar Mensaje');
        } else {
            $('._diifem_').prop({
                disabled: true
            }).attr('data-original-title','Debes ingresar por lo menos un caracter');
        }
    })
});
```

Tambien puedes usar directamente attr:

```
 if (textarea_value.length >= 1) {
        $('._diifem_').attr({
            disabled: false,
            'data-original-title': 'Enviar Mensaje',
        });
    } else {
        $('._diifem_').attr({
            disabled: true,
            'data-original-title': 'Debes ingresar por lo menos un caracter'
        });
    }
```

BTW fijate donde vas a mostrar el tooltip, en el fiddle lo puse debajo (con data-placement) para poder verlo:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary _diifem_"  data-placement="bottom" Value="Enviar mensaje">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó :)